# PHP how to Create special Element <eanucc:countryISOCode xmlns:eanucc="urn:ean.ucc:2">

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create the following element in php to create the xml needed for one of our customers.

every thing works fine but I am not able to find out how I need to create the following element

[image]

I have tried several ways but I am still not able to correctly generate the above example

Can somebody set me on the way?

This is what I have in my coding

```
$eanucc_countryISOCode = $dom->createElement('eanucc','BE');
$eanucc_countryISOCode->setAttribute('xmlns', 'urn:ean.ucc:2');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument - how to add Namespace declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016078/php-domdocument-how-to-add-namespace-declaration)

Comment: I think you need to use the NS-aware version of CreateElement, though I don't remember the details off the top of my head.  http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

`xmlns:eanucc` is a namespace definition for the namespace `urn:ean.ucc:2`. Use the namespace aware DOM methods (with the suffix `NS`).

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document
  ->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS('urn:ean.ucc:2', 'eanucc:countryISOCode')    
  )
  ->appendChild(
    $document->createTextnode('BE')    
  );

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eanucc:countryISOCode xmlns:eanucc="urn:ean.ucc:2">BE</eanucc:countryISOCode>
```

Answer (score -1):

This syntax is the right one!

```
$eanucc_countryISOCode = $doc->createElement('eanucc:countryISOCode','BE');
$eanucc_countryISOCode->setAttribute('xmlns:eanucc', 'urn:ean.ucc:2');
...->appendChild( $eanucc_countryISOCode );
```

Result :

```
<eanucc:countryISOCode xmlns:eanucc="urn:ean.ucc:2">BE</eanucc:countryISOCode>
```

Comment: Hello Yona, THX!!